# Regenerating PHP session ID and double refresh - browser not recieveing the new cookie

Tags: php, codeigniter

I've replaced the somewhat buggy CodeIgniter session library with my own native session implementation.

Both act in the same way, and change the session ID after a certain period of time, and both suffer the same issue, for the sake of this question lets say the session is regenerated each minute.

When a user views a page, and waits one minute, on the next page request the session ID would be regenerated. However there is an issue when the users request times out or if they "double refresh" the page. The browser does not receive the new cookie, which therefore starts a new session on the next request. So if the user hits refresh at the point in which the ID is regenerated and hits refresh again in quick succession, they lose their session.

I know changing the session ID is a good idea to prevent session fixation but is there any way around this issue? Obviously increasing the time in which the ID is regenerated will limit the possibility of this happening but it still seems likely to happen.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: There is a way around this, and most sites don't have this problem, but without some code to look at, we can't be much help.

Comment: Thanks, this is not really an issue with my code - it's more a theoretical question. This issue would affect anyone changing their session id from time to time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Add a column 'previous_session_ID' to your DB
2. Move the current session ID into 'previous_session_ID' - then generate new session ID and store that in the current_session_ID
3. When user tries to access your page with a session ID - check the current ID AND the 'previous_session_ID'

Problem solved - they can now do a 'double refresh' and still access the page.

Comment: In this particular case sessions are not stored in the database. While I guess it's possible to store an additional cookie, I'm not sure if that poses any security issues?

Comment: Where are the sessions stored?

Comment: Natives PHP sessions - But I assume the same would apply? A session variable with the previous ID would do the same job right?

Comment: Thinking about it, this would not work. At the point of a "double refresh" the user ends up with a new empty session. The previous cookie is overwitten with the new session ID and all session data is lost. This method does not work with native sessions and cookies storing the ID

Comment: Why does he end up with a empty session? He has the old session still - thats the whole problem - he never received the 'new' session because of the double refresh. You allow for that old session to be valid using a 'previous_session_ID'.

Comment: The old session is removed, using session_regenerate_id(TRUE). There would be little point leaving lots of old active sessions around when the aim is to prevent session fixation.

Comment: You are only leaving the current session and the previous one. You can then 'shorten' your session rotation time by half, and you actually have the same level of exposure...

Comment: p.s. I should add - I modified the CI session library to do exactly what my answer says (I was using DB sessions) - and it solved this issue for me.